# How can I randomly mutate the rows in a 1d int array without affecting static values that need to remain the same and without introducing repetition?

Tags: java, arrays, genetic-algorithm

I am writing a genetic algorithm to solve a sudoku puzzle and I'm onto the final stage of mutating the generated potential solutions, but am having some trouble with the code.

The result I want to achieve is:

1. The population of 15 chromosomes is looped through
2. Each row is looped through with a 10% chance to mutate
3. Mutation causes 2 random values in the row (1-9) to switch places
4. The mutated row is inserted back into the place in the array it belongs in

I also need to factor in that some of the spaces are defined by the user as the starting board to solve and should not be swapped.

So far in my solution I have another 1d array called non-static values, which holds the positions of which values are allowed to be swapped. I also have a method for creating a 10% chance for the mutation to happen using a random number compared to a "mutation rate" variable.
it

The problem is arising when it comes to putting this all together, as it quickly becomes a complicated mess of nested loops, and since rows are not distinct from each other due to the chromosome being represented as a 1d array.

Currently the code consists of 3 nested loops, with a counter to track the current node up to 80(the 81st node), but this counter is also producing an out of bounds exception as it is reaching 81 for whatever reason.

Code:

```
        public static void mutation(Population population){
    //    Randomise mutation
    //        Set mutation rate
            // 10 percent chance to
            double mutationRate = 0.1;
            int[] row =  new int[9];
    
            //for each chromosome in the population
            for(int i=0; i<15; i++){
    
                //variable for current node
                int currentNode = 0;
                //Placeholder chromosome to grab non-static values from
                Chromosome placeholder = new Chromosome();
                //current chromosome
                Chromosome currChromosome = population.populationMap.get(i);
                placeholder.generateChromosome(Driver.board);
                //putting non-static values into their own list for reference later
                ArrayList<Integer> nonStaticValues = placeholder.getNonStaticValues();
    
    
                // for each row in each chromosome
                for (int j=0; j<9; j++){
                    //determine if row will be mutated
                    //Generate a random probability to determine whether
                    double probability = Math.random();
    
                    for (int k = 0; k < 9; k++){
                        if(probability <= mutationRate ){
                            placeholder.genes[currentNode] = currChromosome.genes[currentNode];
    
    
                        }
                        
                        System.out.println("Current Node: " + currentNode);
                        System.out.println("Current Node Data: "+ currChromosome.genes[currentNode]);
                        currentNode++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Example of expected results

Original Row from csv file of starting board :

```
[0,3,0,0,2,7,8,0,0]
```

After generating the rest of the rows values

```
[9, 3, 5, 1, 2, 7, 8, 6, 4]
```

I want to introduce some more randomness to this but I cannot change the values which start defined from the csv, so the changeable values positions are stored in an array called non-static values.

Example outcome (4 and 9 swap places):

```
[4, 3, 5, 1, 2, 7, 8, 6, 9]
```

Thank you in advance for any help, I hope my question is written properly and code notation helps.

Comment: `currChromosome.genes` is only 80 indexes big, thus the OOB exception. Also it is not quite clear to me what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: genes is 81 in length as  it represents a 9x9 grid, so I'm not sure how to loop through it correctly.  I will add an example below my code to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you applying an algorithm that uses randomness instead of using some approach that is deterministic?

Comment: It's for an AI assignment at university, the algorithm so far has a tournament which selects some winners and then creates a new population from these winners, but the solution is never reached this way as the convergence happens too quickly and it begins producing identical chromosomes which don't improve any more. Random mutation helps solve this issue, but I'm still doubtful if it will ever solve a puzzle, but it doesn't matter too much as long as the concepts are there.

Comment: simplify the code and get rid of the static array. You can just multiple the static number by -1 to distinguish between those that can be modified :)

Comment: 9x9=81 indexes, 0..80. once you get to 81, you are out of bounds

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yeah, looking at what I've got I can see why it's getting to 81 but I'm not sure what I can do to change it, as I need to loop for 9 rows and then 9 elements in each row

Comment: @WeMakeSoftware Hi, not really sure what you mean by this, could you add an example at all?

Comment: move `currentNode++;` as last call in the loop. it fails on `System.out.println("Current Node Data: "+ currChromosome.genes[currentNode]);`

Comment: Ah yeah, that's one problem down then, my original idea for the shuffling part was to use another loop and build an array or the values in a row, but this quickly became convoluted and didn't work out very well

Comment: @BaileyLylyk, share the github repo :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply again, unfortunately I submitted the assignment in the end with a pure random version of the mutation, which is less than optimal but hopefully enough. Thanks again for all the help everyone :)